# K-theory, $K_{0}$ of algebra of compact operators

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, topological-k-theory

I don't understand how to define the trace of a matrix with values in operators. This occurred in the following situation:
Suppose that $H$ is an Hilbert space and $K$ is the algebra of compact operators on $H$.
We proved in the last lecture that
$$K_0(K(H))=\mathbb{Z}$$

In the proof we have seen that every $x\in K_0(K(H))$ has the form $x=[e]-[1_n]$, where $e\in M_N(K)$ is an idempotent with $\epsilon_K(e) \sim 1_n $ and such that $e$ is of finite rank. The map $\epsilon_K$ is defined to be the induced mapping from the mapping $\epsilon$, given by :  $ 0\to K \to \widetilde{K} \xrightarrow{\epsilon}  \mathbb{Z}$.
Now we defined the mapping:
$$tr: K_0(K(H)) \to \mathbb{Z}$$
$$ x\mapsto tr(e-1_n)$$

as the simple trace function.

What is the trace of an operator matrix? 
The whole subject of $K$-Theory is new to me, so maybe I got it totally wrong...

Any explanations are welcome. Thanks.

Comment: It is done p.103 of [Rordam-Larsen-Laustsen](http://books.google.ca/books/about/An_Introduction_to_K_Theory_for_C_Algebr.html?id=SMiB8VIB5UIC&redir_esc=y). A great read.

Comment: unfortunately, i do not have access to this book :( ... another source would be nice

Comment: Are you taking a class on K-theory? Of $C^*$-algebras, I guess. In that case, having access to this book would be a good idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not in position to explain any $K$-theory. But it is not hard to see that $M_n(K(H))\simeq K(\bigoplus_1^nH)$ canonically. So you can see matrices of compact operators as compact operators on a bigger Hilbert space, and you can calculate its trace if it is trace-class.

More concretely, if you have a matrix of operators $T=(T_{kj})_{k,j}\in M_n(B(H))$, its canonical trace (provided that $T$ is trace-class) will be 
$$
\mbox{Tr}(T)=\sum_{j=1}^n\mbox{Tr}(T_{jj}),
$$
where the trace on the left is the one in $B(\oplus_1^n H)$ and the one on the right is that of $B(H)$.

Comment: cool, $M_n(K(H))\simeq K(\bigoplus_1^nH)$ was the thing I missed. Thanks a lot.